# using hello.js not able to post on twiiter

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using [Hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) to access/post social network data.  Hello.JS standardizes paths and responses to common API's.This question in particular is about posting to twitter.

On [twitter demo page](http://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/twitter.html), I logged in with the button and tried hello.api in firebug console. I am able to get the response for

```
>>> hello.api('/me',function(resp) {console.log(resp);})
```

and able to see the response object in console.
While '/me/share' doesn't seem to work, here is the cmd

```
>>> hello.api('/me/share','post',{message:'Hi to all'},
  function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
  })
```

for above reques the response is

```
{"errors":[{"code":170,"message":"Missing required parameter: status"}]}
```

while I see in the Post data as

```
status=Hi%20to%20all
```

and Params are

```
access_token    1690287512-eB8IocvynmqSmnMlpxoh0VBJxWhff86sYHTBqKo:DRT4zO8pTbMjY8yblG9RtSqRMD3oKEyP8kAGG6cpo9w@eQuyZuECKWPiv3D7E4qdg
path    https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?include_entities=1
```

The Hello.js uses [auth-server](https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/) for server side OAuth authentication and authorization. And auth-server is implimentation of [node-oauth-shim](https://github.com/MrSwitch/node-oauth-shim)

Any hint what could be going wrong? Well this may be very vague question.

So my second question to be very specific. In node-oauth-shim [proxy](https://github.com/MrSwitch/node-oauth-shim/blob/master/proxy.js) is used to request to twiiter. In [proxy.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/node-oauth-shim/blob/master/proxy.js) if somebody can help me how to debug if it sends the data to twitter with request or not. Somewhere in code can I do the console log what request(with data) is being sent to twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an implementation bug with Twitter, it was fixed by HelloJS twitter module moving the POST BODY into the URL. e.g.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?include_entities=1&status=Yo+Its+A+Status

Demo is at http://adodson.com/hello.js/#helloapi